# Is this a valid argument $f^{-1}[f(C)] = C$?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

I am given the fact that the function f is injective, and I want to prove the equivalence $f^{-1}[f(C)] = C$ 
My argument was:

"Suppose $x \in f^{-1}[f(C)]$. Since x $\in f^{-1}[f(C)]$, this means that $f(x) \in f(C)$. Now suppose that $z \in C$. Then we know that $f(z) \in f(C)$. Now suppose that $f(z)$ is the exact value that $f(x)$ is. Since we know that f is injective, then x = z, therefore $x \in C.$ Thus $f^{-1}[f(C)] \subseteq C$"

I know I need to prove the other direction, but is this argument sound? Thank you!

Comment: It’s a bit clumsy, but it’s correct. To prove that $f$ is injective if $f^{-1}[f[C]]=C$ for all subsets $C$ of the domain of $f$, consider the case $C=\{x\}$ for any $x$ in the domain. (You could also try assuming that $f$ is **not** injective and proving that there is a $C$ such that $f^{-1}[f[C]]\ne C$.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You really should organize what you are doing. You start with $x$, do some stuff, then set it aside and introduce a new $z$, then come back to $x$... it’s a bit of a mess.

Now, the *idea* seems to be fine, but the presentation isn’t. Let’s organize it a bit better:

To prove that $f^{-1}[f(C)]$, we take $x\in f^{-1}[f(C)]$; we want to show that $x\in C$. So we know that because $x\in f^{-1}[f(C)]$, then $f(x)\in f[C]$. **That** means that there exists $z\in C$ such that $f(z)=f(x)$ (because $y\in f[C]$ if and only if there exists $z\in C$ with $f(z)=y$; so apply this definition with $y=f(x)$). *And* because $f$ is injective, this means that $x=z$. That in turn tells us that $x\in C$ (because $x=z\in C$), which is what we wanted to prove.

That’s what you were doing, but organized as a single flow of arguments, instead of as two separate arguments that somehow meet somewhere in the middle of the paragraph.

The other direction, by the way, should *not* require the use of the hypothesis that $f$ is injective. The condition $X\subseteq f^{-1}[f(X)]$ hold for *any* function.

Comment: Okay, thank you for the help + constructive criticism! :)